# Where do I download Windows 7 home premium SP1 OEM version disk image legally?

Tags: windows-7, windows, disk-image

Is there any legitimate place where I can download Windows 7 home premium SP1 OEM version?
I want to re-install Windows, but I've lost my Windows install disk.

I'm considering downloading the disk from torrents, but I'm afraid of the risk that the files may be corrupted.

Note that the disk is purchased not in combination with a computer or something else. I purchased the OEM version from a retail store because it was cheaper than the consumer version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a legal place to get the ISOs. You need to make sure your key is legal though.

Asked and Answered: [Where can I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft)

Comment: There is no need to post a reference to another question as an answer, as it's either referenced by an automatically inserted comment (now deleted) or the note added to the question.